# unable to switch to edit mode

Tags: edit-mode, object-mode

I'm an absolute Blender newbie and just taking my first steps.
I've created some shape and want to apply coloring and texture now, after placing lamps all around my object to see it, I now can't switch to `Edit Mode` and I'm not sure why, can anybody help me please?

I only have `Object Mode`in the mode selector:

[image]

I'm using version 2.79 on Windows

Comment: What is you just press the "Tab" key?

Comment: Select object which can have other interaction modes first; switching interaction modes is done on the active object. Most likely in your case you have lamp selected and it can't have Edit mode; select a mesh. @rob if there aren't interaction modes available in the dropdown list then Tab won't work as well as it will face the same issue

Comment: @MrZak you should put that in an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had the same isuue (and I'm a COMPLETE newbie to Blender). I just closed the program and opened it again, and then clicked "General" when the program opened again/ the window popped up. Now I've got all the options in the top left-hand corner.

Answer (score 2):

I had this too. I apparently accidentally checked "Lock Object Modes" somehow.
Go to Edit in the menu. Then check off "Lock Object Modes."
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I got this because the object was linked into the scene. I fixed that by right clicking it in Outliner, and selecting Make Local.

Answer (score 1):

I found that edit mode only works when an object is selected. If you can't select it, go to the objects panel and click on your object. Then click tab and you'll switch into edit mode. This is using Blender 2.9.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the original cube in your scene and it works. Delete cube later (Blender2.49b)

Comment: How long must they wait?